# Why did the ordering of my favorite tags change?

Tags: support, tag-watching

I had my favorite tags organized as I wanted them. After a reboot, my favorite tags are now shown in alphabetical order. I liked the order I had them in. Was this an intentional change, a side effect of something else, or are you just trying to drive me mad? (If so, you're out of luck - been there, done that, got the x-tra-long-sleeve t-shirt :-)

Comment: Dang it! I keep clicking on `algorithms` instead of `oracle`. My mind...is a raging torrent, flooded with rivulets of thought, cascading into a waterfall of creative alternatives...Dave...I can feel it going, Dave...Dave...stop...stop, Dave...my mind...is aglow with whirling, transient nodes of thought careening through a cosmic vapor of invention...Dave...stop...or I'll keep mixing quotes like this, Dave...